# Why assigning one pointer to another changes original pointer in cpp?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Suppose headA points to [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11] and headB points to [2, 4 ,9, 11]. I want to find the common intersecting element [problem statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/)

I am not understanding why `a_pointer` and `b_pointer` is returning a null list in the end.

I followed [this](https://youtu.be/IpBfg9d4dmQ) tutorial

> Algorithm followed:(as below)

[image]

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>


    struct ListNode {
        int val;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
        ListNode(int x, ListNode *head) { val = x;  next = head; }
    };


    class Solution {

    public:

        void print(ListNode *head)
        {
            while(head != nullptr)
            {
                printf("%d ->", head->val );
                head = head->next;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        
                ListNode *getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {


                    print(headA);
                    print(headB);

                    ListNode *a_pointer, *b_pointer;
                    a_pointer = headA;
                    b_pointer = headB;

                    while(a_pointer != b_pointer)
                    {
                        

                        if(a_pointer == nullptr)
                        {
                            a_pointer = headB;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            a_pointer = a_pointer->next;
                        }

                        if(b_pointer == nullptr)
                        {
                            b_pointer = headA;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            b_pointer = b_pointer->next;
                        }

                    }

                    print(a_pointer);
                    print(b_pointer);
                    return a_pointer;   

                }


            };



    int main()
    {
        Solution s;
        ListNode *node1 = new ListNode(1);
        node1->next = new ListNode(3);
        node1->next->next = new ListNode(5);
        node1->next->next->next = new ListNode(7);
        node1->next->next->next->next = new ListNode(9);
        node1->next->next->next->next->next = new ListNode(11);

        ListNode *node2 = new ListNode(2);
        node2->next = new ListNode(4);
        node2->next->next = new ListNode(9);
        node2->next->next->next = new ListNode(11);

        
        ListNode *ret = s.getIntersectionNode(node1,node2);
        
    }
```

Comment: It should not change the original pointer. You can however modify what the pointers point to

Comment: but it is, if i `print(headA)` or `print(headB)` before the return statement it returns an empty list.

Comment: Maybe it was empty before you entered.

Comment: see this - https://youtu.be/IpBfg9d4dmQ

Comment: no it wasnt empty

Comment: I think you will have to obtain and use a debugger. Then set a breakpoint and step through this code 1 line at a time looking at the 4 variables after each step.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  It's really hard to tell what you think is wrong from the code provided.

Comment: `a_pointer` will never equal `b_pointer` unless both are nullptr

Comment: @drescherjm it returns a null a_pointer and b_pointer. headA, headB prints okay. My original question was wrong.

Comment: Your checks are incorrect.  `if (a_pointer == nullptr)` should be `if (a_pointer->next == nullptr)` and the same for the `b_pointer` check.  As is you repeatedly loop over both lists until both pointers happen to land on the terminal `nullptr` of one of the lists at the same time.  Once that's fixed, your loop will run infinitely since `a_pointer` will never equal `b_pointer`.  You should be checking `a_pointer->val != b_pointer ->val` as your loop condition.

Comment: With the current code the only time the loop can end is if both `a_pointer` and `b_pointer` were null. Because the second list does not connect to the first list so there is no chance both point to the same node unless it is null.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not understanding why the assignment a_pointer = headB is changing the original headB pointer.

It is reasonable to not understand why original headB pointer would be changed, because the original headB pointer is not being changed.